# How to get ember to work with MongoDB regarding primarykey

Tags: json, mongodb, ember.js, ember-data

I've a MongoDB and get this from JSON:

```
      "_id": {
        "$id": "5364f1fe53db737c089833a1"
      },
```

In ember:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id.$id',
});
```

but I get the following message:

> Assertion Failed: You must include an `id` in a hash passed to `push`.

Without `$id` I get `[object Object]` as the id.

I´m using latest Beta of ember (1.6 Beta 3) and ember data (1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88)

How can I get ember to work?

Comment: `_id: { ... }` doesn't seem to be complete model. What's name of this model and what's full response you get from your API? Is `_id` name of the model if it has its own id?